# Controlling what's serialized in spring + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having issues with understanding exactly how `@Autowire` works, I think. My current issue is with object-based relationships in the data model:

Suppose there's a many-to-one relationship, defined both ways in the model like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Code", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    ...


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CountryCodeA3")
    private Country country;

    ...


@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
public class Country {
    @Column(name = "CodeA2", nullable = false)
    private String codeA2;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CodeA3", nullable = false)
    private String codeA3;

    @Column(name = "CodeNum", nullable = false)
    private String codeNum;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "country")
    private Set<Company> companies;

    ...
```

Then I declare some standard DAOs to access these two objects, and finally the controller (just the relevant function here):

```
@ApiOperation(value = "List of all companies", notes = "List of all companies for our system.", response = Company[].class)
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK") })
@RequestMapping(value = obj_names_api, method =  RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<SmartHttpResult> companyGetAll() {
    final List<Company> list = dao.findAll();

    return Response.getHttpResult(list, list.size() > 0, "/", "COMPANY_NOT_FOUND");
}
```

This will serialize my `Country` and `Company` objects just fine, returning nicely structured JSON objects to the client side. It will walk all the relationships and fetch their appropriate objects.

Sample returned object:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "code": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "country": {
    "codeA2": "string",
    "codeA3": "string",
    "name": "string"
  }
}
```

This is also not what I want.

What I want is to work with objects in Java and serialize simple things like FK field value only for `Company.countryCodeA3`. I also have no need for entire reverse relationship array to come over to the client unless I explicitly tell it to go there (via a separate function). I have no idea how to create a company and specify what country that company is in (without actually adding the entire country object to the POSTed company).

I know how to write the functions to actually retrieve the relations. What I don't know (and that's the question) is how to tell them not to go in-depth when serializing one particular object. I'd like to only send country id over to tell what country this company belongs to - and in case of many-to-many relationships, a list of ids.

So, can I tell Spring + Hibernate to serialize simple objects only and provide the object relationships only via separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways exists, one of them is to use `@JSON` annotation. Using this annotation you can control what fields you should serialize/deserialize or not.

The JSON annotation can be used to mark a field in the object as included by default. Annotations can be placed on the methods or fields. A good example of this might be the Address object that contains a reference to Zipcode object. Since Zipcode is an integral part of every Address (in the US) then it might make more sense for us to default this with the annotation. So in our Address object we could do the following:

```
 public class Address { 
   private String name; 
   private String street; 
   private String city; 
   private String state; 
   private Zipcode zipcode; 

   @JSON 
   public Zipcode getZipcode() { } 
}
```

Annotations can improve your security so that fields that shouldn't be sent over the wire ever can be fixed in one place. That way you keep your code more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), and that prevents accidental security flaws. Consider if we store the a hashed version of a password in our User object.

```
public class User { 
  private String login; 
  private String hashedPassword; 
  private Date lastLogin; 

  @JSON(include=false) 
  public String getHashedPassword() { } 
}
```

Comment: Hm, this annotation would be grand, but my IntelliJ finds it not. I tried a quick google as well with no luck. Is this something built into Spring at all?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Found the @JsonIgnore annotation. It does the same thing your sample does. Still not a complete solution though: What I want is a custom serializer, it seems. Right now I have to declare the same field twice in order to have it serialize as code and work in Java backend as an object.

Comment: It would seem [@JsonAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) would be right for me in this case. It seems I'm getting better at finding this stuff by the minute :)

Comment: If you are using Spring may be better you look in to Jackson libraries? AFIK Spring in charge of them.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jackson, but I'm too much of a noob to actually find this stuff right now... Maybe it's just my link that's wrong, but Jackson has the same annotation. This is just something I was given to work on since my customer is really tight on HR right now.

Comment: @kryger: I accepted it because it put me on the right track. I did however not upvote it. I figured this was the "correct" way of acknowledging nikpon's pointers. Perhaps I shoul've gone just the other way around. Did that now. But I need more research to actually write an answer.

Comment: @kryger This answer is *not* incorrect. And if users will write their own answers and accept them why then OP is asking a question? The problem of readers are just they can/can't read the answer.